# Why won't the correct definition in my code work in an "If/Else" statement?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a quiz for my computer science class and the basic concept is that you have 15 keywords and 15 definitions. All need to be randomly displayed and the correct answer has to appear. The user has to match the correct definition to the keyword twice and then that keyword and definition are not displayed again. When all have been answered twice the quiz is over.

I have stored both my keywords and my definitions in the same file so they don't get out of sync. The text file looks like so:

```
Keyword1,Definition1
Keyword2,Definition2
Keyword3,Definition3
...
```

Thanks to the help from others here on StackOverflow I have managed to get the randomizing and dictionary completed. For reference that looks like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private kv As Dictionary(Of String, Answer) 'Define kv as a dictionary
    Private keyword As String
    Private correctDefinition As String
    Const NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS As Integer = 3 'Define the constant NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS

    Private Sub RandomiseAnswers()
        Dim r As New Random
        Dim kvRandom As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Answer)) =
          kv.OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList

        'questions will appear in random order
        For Each line As KeyValuePair(Of String, Answer) In kvRandom
            Dim keyword As String = line.Key
            Dim correctDefinition As String = line.Value.Answer

            Dim keywords As New List(Of String)
            keywords.Add(keyword)
            keywords.AddRange(kv.Keys.Except({keyword}).
              OrderBy(Function() r.Next).Take(NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS - 1))

            Dim definitionsRandom As List(Of String) =
               keywords.Select(Function(x) kv(x).Answer).OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList

            LabelKeyword.Text = keyword
            RadioButtonDef1.Text = definitionsRandom(0)
            RadioButtonDef2.Text = definitionsRandom(1)
            RadioButtonDef3.Text = definitionsRandom(2)
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'The text file is structured like so:
        'Keyword1,Definition1
        'Keyword2,Definition2
        'Keyword3,Defintion3
        '...
        'This makes sure that the keywords and the definitions do not get out of sync when randomising, as a dictionary is a key-value data structure. Call the key, get the right value etc.
        kv = New Dictionary(Of String, Answer) 'kv = a new dictionary
        For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Matt\Documents\keywords.txt") 'Foreach loop populating the dictionary from the text file
            Dim parts() As String = line.Split(",") 'Split the Keywords from the definitions where the , is
            kv.Add(parts(0), New Answer With {.Answer = parts(1), .Answered = False}) 'Add the two parts (Keyword and Definition) to the Parts with the Answer class
        Next

        Dim r As New Random 'Define r as new random
        Dim kvRandom As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) =
          kv.OrderBy(Function() r.Next) _
    .Select(Function(x) New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(x.Key, x.Value.Answer)) _
    .ToList() 'A Select method to convert the items in the list properly

        'questions will appear in random order
        For Each line As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In kvRandom
            Dim keyword As String = line.Key
            Dim correctDefinition As String = line.Value 'Checks that the correct definition will be displayed when its keyword is randomly displayed.

            'Define keywords as a new list
            Dim keywords As New List(Of String)
            keywords.Add(keyword) 'Adds the keyword to the list as the Part(0) from the text file in the first loop
            keywords.AddRange(kv.Keys.Except({keyword}).
              OrderBy(Function() r.Next).Take(NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS - 1))

            Dim definitionsRandom As List(Of String) =
              keywords.Select(Function(x) kv(x).Answer).OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList 'Define definitionsRandom as a list. Checks against correctDefinition to know to always display the correct answer as one of the 
            'random definitions

            LabelKeyword.Text = keyword 'Randomly display a keyword
            RadioButtonDef1.Text = definitionsRandom(0) 'Randomly display a definition. Checks against correctDefinition to see make sure one definition is always the right answer.
            RadioButtonDef2.Text = definitionsRandom(1) 'Randomly display a definition. Checks against correctDefinition to see make sure one definition is always the right answer.
            RadioButtonDef3.Text = definitionsRandom(2) 'Randomly display a definition. Checks against correctDefinition to see make sure one definition is always the right answer.
        Next

    End Sub



    Private Sub ButtonNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonNext.Click
        'If (RadioButtonDef1.Checked And RadioButtonDef1.Text = correctDefinition) Or (RadioButtonDef2.Checked And RadioButtonDef2.Text = correctDefinition) Or (RadioButtonDef3.Checked And RadioButtonDef3.Text = correctDefinition) Then
        '    If kv(keyword).Answered Then
        '        kv.Remove(keyword)
        '    Else
        '        kv(keyword).Answered = True
        '    End If
        'Else
        '    MsgBox("Incorrect Answer!")
        'End If
        If (RadioButtonDef1.Checked And RadioButtonDef1.Text = correctDefinition) Or (RadioButtonDef2.Checked And RadioButtonDef2.Text = correctDefinition) Or (RadioButtonDef3.Checked And RadioButtonDef3.Text = correctDefinition) Then
            MsgBox("Correct Answer")
        Else
            MsgBox("Incorrect Answer. The correct answer is: " & correctDefinition)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I use a subroutine in my `buttonNext_click` to prevent duplicate code, as you can see above `Private Sub RandomiseAnswers()`.

my issue however is when I come down to the `If/else` statement where I determine whether the user has selected the correct answer. As you can see I have commented out the original line as I found that it didn't work, and therefore I created one which would display a message box. By using that `If/Else` statement I have found that it always displays the `Incorrect Answer` message box and it doesn't display the correct definition.

What is puzzling me the most is that I know that `correctDefinition` works as it will always  display the correct definition to the current keyword however I cannot seem to fathom out how to make it work in the conditional/s.

Does anyone have a possible solution as to why it doesn't seem to like being used in the `If/Else` statement/s but does work when randomising.

Sorry if it is hard to understand what I am asking.

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDITS**

code relevant to the `Answer class`

```
   Public Class Answer
    Public Answer As String
    Public Answered As Boolean
End Class
```

Comment: in the radio button checkchanged event you could capture the selected answer as a form level var.  then you just have to test if `SelectedAnswer = CorrectAnswer` (easier) just be sure to clear the answer when you display the next set.

Comment: What do you mean? So change the `If/Else` statement to radionbutton_checkedChanged?

Comment: in the radiobutton(s) checkchanged event you could capture the answer there to make the evaluation simpler: `If SelectedAnswer = CorrectAnswer` and not worry about which RB is checked.

Comment: @MattKent - basically you have a couple of things in your `if` condition. So I suggest that you debug them both one by one, i.e. make sure that the correct radio button is coming as selected and the text matching is working fine. I would also say that instead of using `=` do it like this: `RadioButtonDef1.Text.Equals(correctDefinition, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`. I am assuming that `correctDefinition` indeed holds the correct string otherwise my first doubt is definitely on it

Comment: I got this when debugging: `Conversion from string "Definition1" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.` How can I convert correctDefinition to string? The Answer class is a boolean and `correctDefinition` is equal to `line.value.Answer`.

Answer (score 0):

You declare correctDefinition twice in your code.  Declare it once or better yet make correctDefinition an array eg.

```
Private correctDefinition() String = New String() { "Definition 1", "Definition 2", "Definition 3" }
```